# Android ListView custom row overlay

Tags: android, listview, overlay

I am developing an activity with a ListView in which I need to change the current row by another layout by clicking on the row, and I'm not finding any way to do as much as I look (I take hours searching for possible solutions and I have not seen any reference to this problem). I do not know if this can be done in Android, but if anyone has an idea of ​​how to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

PS: The ListView control is normal and just want to replace a layout with a different layout. I'm using the API 15.

Comment: As added @r2DoesInc response, it is true that you can only add two views to a ViewSwitcher, but one of those views may be another ViewSwitcher which itself contains more views, so that it can generate multiple consecutive seamlessly views that can be displayed one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ViewSwitcher`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html

A `ViewSwitcher` is -

> ViewAnimator that switches between two views, and has a factory from
>   which these views are created. You can either use the factory to
>   create the views, or add them yourself. A ViewSwitcher can only have
>   two child views, of which only one is shown at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest merging the two layouts in a single one and hide the second one. In your adapter data you should have a flag or something to indicate which layout to display. When you click a row, toggle that flag for the selected item and `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. This will make sure the changed layout remains even if you scroll up and down and the row goes off screen.

A more optimized solution is to have different [item types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) in the adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the response of @r2DoesInc is right for my case because ViewSwitcher automates all operations and also adds animation to the whole.